# Cannot connect to ftp - batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, ftp

I have simple batch file to copy multiple files to FTP. I tried many things, but in dir.txt i see, that I am not at FTP server, but in Local directory. Why i cannot to start ftp? :)

I have 2 files:

first.bat

```
upload.bat > log.txt
ftp -i -s:upload.bat
```

upload.bat

```
open myftp.myadress.com
name
password
dir >> dir.txt
cd testfolder
cd cielovy
prompt
bin
mput C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\FTPtest\upload\*
bye
```

Thanks :)

---

After editing batch files and run, it wrotes:
[cmd.exe image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0M9yE.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You are running a batch file to log the commands to a file `log.txt`, but you are calling the batch file from ftp.

instead try this:

```
"C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\FTPtest\upload.bat" > log.txt
cd "C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\FTPtest\upload"
ftp -i -s:"C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\FTPtest\log.txt"
```

Secondly, your batch file is wrong. If you want to create a file for ftp -I to read you need to ensure that the commands are piped to the file for instance everything should pipe, currently you are running the commands and piping the output to log.txt

```
echo open myftp.myadress.com
echo name
echo password
echo dir >> dir.txt  # This however will not do what you think it would.
echo cd testfolder
echo cd cielovy
echo prompt
echo bin
echo mput *
echo bye
```

Comment: This + `dir >> dir.txt` does not work in `ftp` script file.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Yes, there is a lot he needs to change though, currently he is piping output of the commands to log.txt as well.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. But it still not work work with FTP. Script work still in Local... Part of log.txt - `C:\Users\DavidL\Desktop\FTPtest>echo cd testfolder 
cd testfolder`

Comment: are you doing `ftp -i -s:log.txt` ?

Comment: how are you executing it?

Comment: I open first.bat, thats all.

Comment: and what is the current first.bat content exactly?

Comment: `upload.bat > log.txt`
`ftp -i -s:log.txt`

Comment: ok, and when you run the script from cmd.exe what errors do you see? or output? Please capture the output or error and edit your question to add it.

Comment: @David I updated my answer. Please see both the code sections where I `cd` and then run the batch and also the `mput` portion.

Comment: Thanks, great idea. But in this case as you wrote I must have upload.bat in same folder like copied files. But I dont want to copy upload.bat. I solved this, that I give this row - `upload.bat > log.txt`  to first row. And second problem is - when I copy upload.bat to this folder and It run, so it seems like everything is OK, but nothing is copied :(

Comment: put `upload.bat` in `C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\FTPtest`